# MPI OpenMP Hybrid slower than Pure MPI

Tags: c, mpi, openmp

With pure MPI, my runtime is 3.7s

With hybrid MPI + OpenMP, my runtime becomes 4.1s

pure MPI ran with 16 nodes, 1 core each.

pure MPI ran with 1 node, 16 cores.

Hybrid MPI + OpenMP ran with 16 nodes, 16 cores each

I have tried printf debug and all processes are handed 16 cores as expected.

Any insight would help!

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myRank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numNodes);

while ( dtMain > MAX_TEMP_ERROR && iteration <= max_iterations ) {
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j)
    for(i = 1; i <= ROWS; i++) {
        for(j = 1; j <= COLUMNS; j++) {
            Temperature[i][j] = 0.25 * (Temperature_last[i+1][j] + Temperature_last[i-1][j] +
                                        Temperature_last[i][j+1] + Temperature_last[i][j-1]);
        }
    }

    if(myRank != LAST) {
        MPI_Send(&Temperature[ROWS][1], COLUMNS, MPI_DOUBLE, myRank + 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    if(myRank != FIRST) {
        MPI_Recv(&Temperature_last[0][1], COLUMNS, MPI_DOUBLE, myRank - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
    if(myRank != FIRST) {
        MPI_Send(&Temperature[1][1], COLUMNS, MPI_DOUBLE, myRank - 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    if(myRank != LAST) {
        MPI_Recv(&Temperature_last[ROWS + 1][1], COLUMNS, MPI_DOUBLE, myRank + 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
    dt = 0.0; // reset largest temperature change
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j) reduction(max:dt)
    for(i = 1; i <= ROWS; i++){
        for(j = 1; j <= COLUMNS; j++){
              dt = fmax( fabs(Temperature[i][j]-Temperature_last[i][j]), dt);
              Temperature_last[i][j] = Temperature[i][j];
        }
    }
    MPI_Allreduce(&dt, &dtMain, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

      iteration++;
}
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: This does not look like a [mcve].

Comment: Note your program might be too fast to hide the MPI initialization, so your measurement might be biased. How did you measure pure MPI = 3.7s ? 1 node and 16 tasks per node ? 16 nodes and 1 task per node ? what is the topology of your 16 cores nodes ? 1 socket and 16 cores ? 2 sockets and 16 cores each ? is there any hyper threading ? what if you run 32 MPI tasks on 16 nodes and 8 OpenMP threads per node ? What if you run 1 MPI task with 16 OpenMP threads ?